# Private cloud solution [Eucalyptus,OpenStack, Nimbus] for Java deployments [Glassfish, Tomcat]

Tags: java, cloud, glassfish, eucalyptus, openstack

I am interested in a way to have private cloud which would host Glassfish (or Tomcat) server.

Which option from Eucalyptus, Openstack or Nimbus would be best to deploy java applications on it? Or maybe there is something other and I am looking wrong at the problem?

The way I imagine this, that I should have some shared storage that I could expand by introducing new nodes to this cluster and have easy management for glassfish instances: something like virtual machines images that I can start and stop on demand and that image is shared among nodes.

I don't need concrete step-by-step solution here but guidelines how this should be done are very welcome.

Comment: you probably want to reverse the question, and specify your requirements in terms of performance, reliability, scalability etc.

Comment: glassfish supports centralized administration of glassfish clusters using the web console - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24934/ssh-setup.htm#gkshg

Answer (score 2):

You should check Open PaaS like Cloudify, which I'm one of its contributors (see http://www.cloudifysource.org).
Using such Open PaaS can really give you the freedom to pick any Private Cloud.
Cloudify can easily on board any service (e.g. Websphere), on any cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Typically Eucalyptus and Openstack are about scaling server instances (or S3/swift storage) rather than clustering individual applications.

Hence if you wish to deploy a cluster of a specific java application for performance, reliability and scalability, then for the 2 types of java application server you mentioned, you should consider either a Glassfish server cluster, or a tomcat cluster.

[Glassfish high availability](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24934/toc.htm) supports load balancing over [glassfish server clusters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24934/clusters.htm#gjfom) in the open source edition, [session replication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24934/overview.htm#gaynn) and fail over. You can achieve further protection by using the various database High availability strategies, such as [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) or some NoSQL or Postgresql equivalent.

You can achieve similar results (some would argue..;-) with [tomcat session replication](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html), or other high availability, and failover strategies with tomcat clusters.

Obviously it very much depends on what you are trying to achieve, and the structure and components of your Java Application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/)

> OpenShift is Red Hat's free, auto-scaling Platform as a Service (PaaS) for applications. As an application platform in the cloud, OpenShift manages the stack so you can focus on your code.